# Setting object properties with Trigger in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, triggers, styles

I have a strange problem, I'm currently trying to styling a SingleUpDown Control (from Extended WPF Toolkit)

This is the current style that does **not** work:

```
<xctk:SingleUpDown>
    <xctk:SingleUpDown.Style>
        <Style TargetType="xctk:SingleUpDown">    
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding _ThresoldLocked}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Value" Value="2"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </xctk:SingleUpDown.Style>
</xctk:SingleUpDown>
```

While these two examples work like a charm:

```
<xctk:SingleUpDown>
    <xctk:SingleUpDown.Style>
        <Style TargetType="xctk:SingleUpDown">    
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding _ThresoldLocked}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </xctk:SingleUpDown.Style>
</xctk:SingleUpDown>
```

Or

```
<xctk:SingleUpDown>
    <xctk:SingleUpDown.Style>
        <Style TargetType="xctk:SingleUpDown">    
            <Setter Property="Value" Value="2"/>
        </Style>
    </xctk:SingleUpDown.Style>
</xctk:SingleUpDown>
```

What I'm doing wrong with the first Style? 
There's no Error in the Output window..

EDIT:
This is my minimalist example:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/EzxBP.png
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: All styles look like they would work (in combination with those instances), are you really using just the code as shown?

Comment: Yeah, I've updated my question with a screenshot.
If I press the "up" or "down" arrow, or simply type a number, it correctly work.

Answer (score 1):

Usually when it comes to styles and triggers people are not aware of [precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), namely that **local values** among others completely override styles. Given the fact that you did not set any properties on the controls all styles *should* work.

So for example if you set the `Value` on your control (`<xctk:SingleUpDown Value="0">...`) the trigger does nothing, you would then move defaults into a `Setter`.

```
<xctk:SingleUpDown>
    <xctk:SingleUpDown.Style>
        <Style TargetType="xctk:SingleUpDown">
            <Setter Property="Value" Value="<default here>"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding _ThresoldLocked}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Value" Value="2"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </xctk:SingleUpDown.Style>
</xctk:SingleUpDown>
```

**Edit:**

I made an observation about the control's behaviour. If you have a setup as shown above the Trigger will work, so the default setter is kind of necessary here.

Also you should note that manipulating the value will probably set it locally, thus overriding any further effects from the trigger. You can get around this by using animations instead of triggers as they have the highest precedence, however this may then void any manual manipulation.

Maybe you should move your logic away from the UI and just bind the `Value` directly to a property on your view-model/model, e.g.

```
private bool _ThresholdLocked;
public bool ThresholdLocked
{
    get { return _ThresholdLocked; }
    set
    {
        if (value != _ThresholdLocked)
        {
            _ThresholdLocked= value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ThresholdLocked");
            OnPropertyChanged("Value"); //Value is also affected
        }
    }
}

private float _Value;
public float Value
{
    get
    {
        if (ThresholdLocked)
            return 2.0f;

        return _Value;
    }
    set
    {
        if (value != _Value)
        {
            _Value = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Value");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Jamby: See some changes to my answer. Also i think the control is just kind of bad, this would easily work for a lot of other controls i know...

Comment: @Jamby: Btw, your "Threshold" seems to be lacking an "h".

Comment: Yeah, I think that this solution would work, but I don't really like it, 'cause it's lot more unreadable and hardcoded in the code behind, while I tend to take all of the UI logic in the XAML (moreover, 'cause this simple form isn't developed in MVVM)
However, the main reason because I don't like this solution is that a Background Setter works, so I don't get it why the Value Setter does not..
PS: Thanks for correct my typo.

Answer (score 0):

I using Extended WPF Toolkit, but I don't have `SingleUpDown` there, but you probably talking about different version than this is: http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/. I have there `DoubleUpDown` and your nonfunctional style works for me.

Comment: Nope.. Even with DoubleUpDown I can't get it working.. Anyway, SingleUpDown documentation is found here: http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=SingleUpDown

Comment: Yes. I found that too. But If I understood right It is only in paid version? But it's strange that it works for me and not for you.